# How to build apk file from Quasar Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, quasar

With Quasar Cordova, the build command for release used to generate apk file.
Now it generates aab file.
Is there any command options to instruct it to build release apk instead of aab file?

Answer (score 2):

There you go, you need to add these flags,

```
quasar build -m android -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

Comment: still getting aab file